# GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY in lwjgl not working

Tags: java, opengl, textures, rendering, lwjgl

I'm having issues useing GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY in lwjgl to replace a GL_TEXTURE_2D. All textures just show up as a plain white.What am I missing?

And does any one know of a simple example program that uses GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY in lwjgl or at least an example program another C-based programming language that has beginning to end compile instructions?

What I want:

[image: Image showing textures]

What I get:

[image: Image showing nontextured white cube]

I've striped much of my project's logic out in attempt to minimize the code.

Test.java:

```
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL12;
import org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU;

public class Test {
    private Texture3D texture;
    private VertexBuffer mainCube;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Test().run();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        this.setup();
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            this.render();
            Display.sync(60);
            Display.update();
        }
        this.destroy();
    }

    private void setup() throws Exception {
        Display.setTitle("Game");
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(600, 400));
        Display.create();
        Test.checkForGLError("setupDisplay");
        this.texture = new Texture3D("res/images/textures.png");
        this.texture.buildBuffer();
        this.texture.bufferData();
        Test.checkForGLError("setupTexture");
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
        GL11.glCullFace(GL11.GL_BACK);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(90.0f, 1.5f, 0.1f, 1000.0F);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glTranslatef(0, 0, -4);
        GL11.glEnable(GL12.GL_TEXTURE_3D);
        Test.checkForGLError("setupCamera");
        this.mainCube = new VertexBuffer();
        int vi0, vi1, vi2, vi3;
        // Top
        vi0 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(0f, 0f, 0f));
        vi1 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(1f, 1f, -1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(0f, 1f, 0f));
        vi2 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(-1f, 1f, -1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(1f, 1f, 0f));
        vi3 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(-1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(1f, 0f, 0f));
        this.mainCube.addIndices(vi0, vi1, vi2);
        this.mainCube.addIndices(vi2, vi3, vi0);
        // Bottom
        vi0 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(-1f, -1f, 1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(0f, 0f, 1f));
        vi1 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(-1f, -1f, -1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(0f, 1f, 1f));
        vi2 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(1f, -1f, -1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(1f, 1f, 1f));
        vi3 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(1f, -1f, 1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(1f, 0f, 1f));
        this.mainCube.addIndices(vi0, vi1, vi2);
        this.mainCube.addIndices(vi2, vi3, vi0);
        // North
        vi0 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(1f, 1f, -1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(0f, 0f, 2f));
        vi1 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(1f, -1f, -1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(0f, 1f, 2f));
        vi2 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(-1f, -1f, -1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(1f, 1f, 2f));
        vi3 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(-1f, 1f, -1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(1f, 0f, 2f));
        this.mainCube.addIndices(vi0, vi1, vi2);
        this.mainCube.addIndices(vi2, vi3, vi0);
        // South
        vi0 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(-1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(0f, 0f, 3f));
        vi1 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(-1f, -1f, 1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(0f, 1f, 3f));
        vi2 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(1f, -1f, 1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(1f, 1f, 3f));
        vi3 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(1f, 0f, 3f));
        this.mainCube.addIndices(vi0, vi1, vi2);
        this.mainCube.addIndices(vi2, vi3, vi0);
        // East
        vi0 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(0f, 0f, 4f));
        vi1 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(1f, -1f, 1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(0f, 1f, 4f));
        vi2 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(1f, -1f, -1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(1f, 1f, 4f));
        vi3 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(1f, 1f, -1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(1f, 0f, 4f));
        this.mainCube.addIndices(vi0, vi1, vi2);
        this.mainCube.addIndices(vi2, vi3, vi0);
        // West
        vi0 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(-1f, 1f, -1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(0f, 0f, 5f));
        vi1 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(-1f, -1f, -1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(0f, 1f, 5f));
        vi2 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(-1f, -1f, 1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(1f, 1f, 5f));
        vi3 = this.mainCube.addVertex(new VertexBuffer.Vertex().setVertexCoords(-1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setColors(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f).setTextureCoords(1f, 0f, 5f));
        this.mainCube.addIndices(vi0, vi1, vi2);
        this.mainCube.addIndices(vi2, vi3, vi0);
        this.mainCube.buildBuffers();
        this.mainCube.bufferData();

        GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        Test.checkForGLError("setupMainCube");
    }

    private void render() {
        GL11.glPushMatrix();
        {
            long currnet_timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            GL11.glRotated((currnet_timestamp / 30.0) % 360.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
            GL11.glRotated((currnet_timestamp / 20.0) % 360.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            GL11.glRotated((currnet_timestamp / 10.0) % 360.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            this.texture.bind();
            {
                this.mainCube.render();
            }
            this.texture.unbind();
        }
        GL11.glPopMatrix();
        Test.checkForGLError("render");
    }

    private void destroy() {
        this.texture.destroyBuffer();
        this.mainCube.destroyBuffers();
        Display.destroy();
    }

    public static void checkForGLError(String string) {
        int errorFlag = GL11.glGetError();
        if (errorFlag != GL11.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            System.out.println(string + ": " + GLU.gluErrorString(errorFlag));
        }
    }
}
```

Texture3D.java:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL12;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;

public class Texture3D {
    private static final int BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 4;

    public static BufferedImage loadImage(String loc) {
        try {
            File file = new File(loc);
            return ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Error Handling Here
        }
        return null;
    }

    private int textureId;
    private int height = 1;
    private int width = 1;
    private int depth = 6;
    private int[] pixels;

    public Texture3D(String loc) {
        this.loadTexture(Texture3D.loadImage(loc));

    }

    void loadTexture(BufferedImage image) {
        this.width = image.getWidth();
        this.height = image.getHeight() / this.depth;
        this.pixels = new int[this.width * this.height * 6];
        image.getRGB(0, 0, this.width, this.height, this.pixels, 0, this.width);
    }

    public ByteBuffer buildPixelBuffer() {
        ByteBuffer pixelBuffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(this.width * this.height * this.depth * Texture3D.BYTES_PER_PIXEL);
        for (int y = 0; y < (this.height * 6); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
                int pixel = this.pixels[(y * this.width) + x];
                pixelBuffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF)); // Red component
                pixelBuffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF)); // Green
                // component
                pixelBuffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF)); // Blue component
                pixelBuffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF)); // Alpha
                // component
            }
        }
        pixelBuffer.flip();
        return pixelBuffer;
    }

    public void buildBuffer() {
        this.textureId = GL11.glGenTextures();
    }

    public void bufferData() {
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, this.textureId);
        GL12.glTexImage3D(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA8, this.width, this.height, this.depth, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, this.buildPixelBuffer());
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
        GL11.glTexParameteri(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0);
    }

    public void bind() {
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, this.textureId);
    }

    public void unbind() {
        GL11.glBindTexture(GL30.GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0);
    }

    public void destroyBuffer() {
        GL11.glDeleteTextures(this.textureId);
    }

}
```

VertexBuffer.java:

```
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;

public class VertexBuffer {
    public static class Vertex {
        public float[] pos;
        public float[] color;
        public float[] tex;

        Vertex setVertexCoords(float x, float y, float z, float w) {
            this.pos = new float[] { x, y, z, w };
            return this;
        }

        Vertex setColors(float r, float g, float b, float a) {
            this.color = new float[] { r, g, b, a };
            return this;
        }

        Vertex setTextureCoords(float s, float t, float r) {
            this.tex = new float[] { s, t, r };
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static final int stride = 11 * 4;
    public static final int vertexOffset = 0 * 4;
    public static final int colorOffset = 4 * 4;
    public static final int texCoordOffset = 8 * 4;
    List<Vertex> rawVertexs = new LinkedList<Vertex>();
    List<short[]> rawIndicesSets = new LinkedList<short[]>();
    private int vertexBufferHandle;
    private int indexBufferHandle;
    private int indexBufferLength;
    private boolean dirty = false;
    private boolean hasBuffers = false;

    public int addVertex(Vertex vertex) {
        this.rawVertexs.add(vertex);
        this.dirty = true;
        return this.rawVertexs.size() - 1;
    }

    public void addIndices(int index0, int index1, int index2) {
        this.rawIndicesSets.add(new short[] { (short) index0, (short) index1, (short) index2 });
        this.dirty = true;
    }

    public FloatBuffer getVertexBuffer() {
        FloatBuffer verticesBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(this.rawVertexs.size() * 11);
        for (Vertex vertex : this.rawVertexs) {
            verticesBuffer.put(vertex.pos);
            verticesBuffer.put(vertex.color);
            verticesBuffer.put(vertex.tex);
        }
        verticesBuffer.flip();
        return verticesBuffer;
    }

    public ShortBuffer getIndicesBuffer() {
        ShortBuffer indicesBuffer = BufferUtils.createShortBuffer(this.rawIndicesSets.size() * 3);
        for (short[] rawVertexIndexSet : this.rawIndicesSets) {
            indicesBuffer.put(rawVertexIndexSet);
        }
        indicesBuffer.flip();
        return indicesBuffer;
    }

    public int getIndicesCount() {
        return this.rawIndicesSets.size() * 3;
    }

    public void buildBuffers() {
        if (this.hasBuffers) {
            return;
        }
        this.vertexBufferHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        this.indexBufferHandle = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    }

    public void bufferData() {
        if (!this.hasBuffers) {
            this.buildBuffers();
        }
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexBufferHandle);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.getVertexBuffer(), GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indexBufferHandle);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.getIndicesBuffer(), GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        this.indexBufferLength = this.getIndicesCount();
        this.dirty = false;
    }

    public void render() {
        if (this.dirty) {
            this.bufferData();
        }
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexBufferHandle);
        {
            GL11.glVertexPointer(4, GL11.GL_FLOAT, VertexBuffer.stride, VertexBuffer.vertexOffset);
            GL11.glColorPointer(4, GL11.GL_FLOAT, VertexBuffer.stride, VertexBuffer.colorOffset);
            GL11.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, VertexBuffer.stride, VertexBuffer.texCoordOffset);
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indexBufferHandle);
            {
                GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, this.indexBufferLength, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
            }
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        }
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    void destroyBuffers() {
        if (!this.hasBuffers) {
            return;
        }
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(this.vertexBufferHandle);
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(this.indexBufferHandle);
    }
}
```

texture.png:

[image: texture for covering cube]

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if you are trying to use array textures with the fixed function pipeline. This is just not possible in the GL. You *must* use shaders if you want to access array textures. The `GL11.glEnable(GL12.GL_TEXTURE_3D);` is enabling a 3D texture, which you haven't bound, and `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` is not a 3D texture, it is just reusing the `TexImage3D()` functions because of the similiarities of the input data layout.

If you really want to use the fixed function pipeline, you *might* be able to use a real 3D texture instead - and have to live with the drawbacks (filtering and mipmapping between layers, lower limit on texture dimensions and so on).

My advice would be to drop the deprecated fixed function pipeline and switch to shaders, though.

Comment: As a beginner, I always found shaders very confusing. I wouldn't actually agree with telling a beginner to switch to shaders yet, just because it's an entire new world and I personally found that one needs to get used to the OpenGL code first and then gradually move into shaders. Yes I do use shaders, but even now I still use some fixed-function pipeline things at times.

Comment: @Joehot200: well, people do have personal experiences and opinions. I really try to separate the facts in my answer from personal opinion (to a certain degree), that's why I mentioned 3D textures as a possible alternative. However, in _my_ opinion, nobody starting with GL nowadays should even consider the fixed-function pipeline anymore. From my experience, shaders are getting much more confusing when one is used to the fixed-function stuff, not when one learns it that way from scratch. YMMV.

Comment: Unfortunately when I started 3 years ago I only had TheCodingUniverse's tutorials to work from, which were all using fixed-function or copied-in shaders. Now that people like ThinMatrix have come about which force me to learn shaders, then it sort-of feels like another world. I personally wouldn't force it upon a beginner. However, I definitely agree that it would be much better to learn shaders from an earlier stage rather than a later one.